# Data visualisation library that works on all browsers

Tags: java, javascript, ios, flash, data-visualization

Please recommend a data visualisation library that meets the following requirements:

1. works on all popular browsers (including ios safari)

2. java compatible

3. open-source (preferable)

So far I have used BirdEye (a comprehensive open source information visualization and visual analytics library for Adobe Flex) http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/

Pros of BirdEye: open source

Cons of BirdEye: does not work on ios browsers (it is flash-based)

I don't want to write a native app for iOS. Hence, I need something like BirdEye which works on iOS as well.

The primary goal of that application is to draw graphs for strategy map.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "java compatible"? What interaction with Java is needed? Be aware that Java's browser penetration figures are pretty poor - substantially worse than flash: http://www.statowl.com/custom_ria_market_penetration.php

Answer (score 4):

I have worked on google visualization API. I found it easy to use and supports wide range of options. Also their site has good sample code so learning curve is smooth.

I had done it for iOS safari. But I think, its supported on all major browsers because it's a Javascript based library.

[visualization API of Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)

Answer (score 2):

How sophisticated does it need to be?

- If you just need **standard charting** like interactive line charts, bars, stacked bars, pie charts, dot charts, etc then go with **[gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)**. It's built on [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) which uses SVG or VML (IE6-8's weird SVG clone) as appropriate. It works in IE6+, all major desktop browsers, iOS Safari, and modern Android stock browsers. The only browser I'm aware of where it doesn't work in is the stock Android browser in Android versions 1 and 2 - i.e. old Android phones (not tablets, which use v3) from mid 2011 or earlier, where the user hasn't replaced the stock browser or updated.

[image]   [image]

- If you need **serious stuff**, look into taking the output from **[D3.js](http://d3js.org/)** (an awesome SVG data visualisation library used in many of the most sophisticated data visualisations on the web, including most of the New York Times' [award-winning interactive visualisations](http://blog.visual.ly/10-things-you-can-learn-from-the-new-york-times-data-visualizations/), for example) and pipe it through Raphael to make it cross-browser. D3 outputs SVG paths and shapes, and Raphael takes SVG path strings and shape co-ordinates as input... Getting the two libraries working together is never actually that simple, but it's not a major struggle either - here's [a blog article on how to do it](http://dataist.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/combining-d3-and-raphael-to-make-a-network-graph/) using a force-directed graph as an example. Of course, while this is great for cross-browser compatibility, it uses a lot of processing power. Optimise for performance, and consider using some loading animation spinning gif :-)

[image] [image]

---

**Tip:** If you're doing anything serious with Raphael that involves manipulating paths or shapes using or looking at their bounding box dimensions, and if the latest version or the version you're using is 2.1 or earlier (as it is at time of writing), [apply this bug fix](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/543) to avoid strange unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I liked to use (after some research):
 
[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/)
[InfoVis](http://philogb.github.com/jit/)
[highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Enjoy!